# PDFBOX - Sign AcroForm PDSignatureField

Tags: android, pdfbox

I have an existing AcroForm which i want to sign using PDSignatureField.
I can't find the method where i set the value (Bitmap) of the field.

SetValue expecting PDSignature object, but this object has no method for setting the Bitmap.

```
val signature = PDSignature()
signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED)
signature.setContents(image)

acroForm?.isSignaturesExist = true
acroForm?.isAppendOnly = true

val treeNode = acroForm?.getField(fieldName) as PDSignatureField
treeNode.value = signature
```

I tried setContents with the bimtap byteArray but no result.

Answer (score 1):

You had better look at the official PDFBox example code for creating digital PDF signatures, e.g. [CreateVisibleSignature2.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature2.java).

You will in particular see that there an image is not directly injected into `PDSignature` but instead built into an annotation in a template PDF:

```java
// create a template PDF document with empty signature and return it as a stream.
private InputStream createVisualSignatureTemplate(PDDocument srcDoc, int pageNum, PDRectangle rect) throws IOException
{
    try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument())
    {
        [...]

        try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, appearanceStream))
        {
            [...]
            cs.saveGraphicsState();
            cs.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(0.25f, 0.25f));
            PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension(imageFile, doc);
            cs.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            cs.restoreGraphicsState();
            [...]
        }

        // no need to set annotations and /P entry

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        doc.save(baos);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

This template PDF which is used during signing:

```java
public void signPDF(File inputFile, File signedFile, Rectangle2D humanRect, String tsaUrl, String signatureFieldName) throws IOException
{
    [...]

        signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
        signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(doc, 0, rect));
        signatureOptions.setPage(0);
        doc.addSignature(signature, signatureInterface, signatureOptions);

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did implement it for some of my tests. Please note this code is using PdfBox Version 2.X

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

import org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateSignature;
import org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateVisibleSignature;
import org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.TSAClient;

public class SigningTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SigningTest t = new SigningTest();
    t.signVisible();
}    
public void signVisible() throws Exception{
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream("YourKeystore.p12"),"PWD".toCharArray());

    File documentFile = new File("ThePdfYouWantToSign.pdf");

    CreateVisibleSignature signing = new CreateVisibleSignature(keystore,"PWD".toCharArray());
    FileInputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream("YourSignatureImage.png");
    File signedDocumentFile = new File("TheSignedFile.pdf");
    
    signing.setVisibleSignDesigner(-85, imageStream);
    imageStream.close();
    signing.setVisibleSignatureProperties("name", "location", "Security", true);
    signing.setExternalSigning(false);
   
    signing.signPDF(documentFile, signedDocumentFile, null,"SignatureFieldName");
}
```

Comment: can you share your whole code of your test project?

Comment: @GianhTran Yeah sure but it is just some boilerplate code... **Update**: Did add the rest of the test code